# How to add a string to a new line and return it to a modal popup

Tags: c#, html

I have a string variable that that is returned on the modal pop up and I am trying to arrange it and put every line in a new line,  but it looks fine on the online compiler but when I am compiling it on visual studio it breaks.

```
if(linebyline.IndexOf(findError, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
{
    errCount++;
    errorList += linebyline ;
    errorList = Regex.Replace(errorList, @"(/\$?\{(\d+)\}/g)", "<br />");
}
```

This is how my pop up currently look.

[image]

Comment: Try using `Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: Can you share some  more code. What is raw data and what output you want? Details of variables and functions you used.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is nothing match the Regex, so there is no `<br />` tag in your errorList. You can try add `<br />` tag after linebyline variable.

```
if(linebyline.IndexOf(findError, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
{
    errCount++;
    errorList += linebyline + "<br />" ;
}
```